# Protractor get iconbutton element

Tags: angular, protractor, angular2-testing

```
<td style="width: 20px;">
  <IconButton [Name]="'Signout'" [IsIconOnly]="true (click)="OnSignoutClicked()" title="Sign Out"></IconButton>
</td>
```

How can I locate the above element in Protractor?
I want to simulate a click on the element, not to expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by `title`:

```
$("IconButton[title='Sign Out']").click();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked perfectly . but if I can ask why this didn't work  ? ::                var SignOutbtn = element(by.css("img[src*='../Images/Icons/Signout.png']"));
        
       SignOutbtn.click();

Comment: @anasz3z3 glad it worked. Difficult to say, I don't see the `img` tag in the HTML in the question..